# Not able to set same name for Azure key Vault in different Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am trying to set same name to all my Key Vault in different Subscription but getting below error.

```
New-AzureRmKeyVault : VaultAlreadyExists: The name 'AKeyVault' is already in use.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName AKeyVault -ResourceGroupName PS ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmKeyVault], CloudException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.NewAzureKeyVault
```

can someone please let me know if key vault name should be unique across all subscriptions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, the `Key Vault` name should be universally unique as key vault and keys/secrets inside it  are accessed via `https://{vault-name}.vault.azure.net` URI. It's very much like storage account name. If I create a storage account by the name `nkdev`, then you can't use that name.

Comment: Is it universally unique across Clouds tenants, e.g. Worldwide, Germany, China etc.

Comment: Nope. As the endpoints differ in these regions....so you could have a key vault with the same name in East US and US Gov.

Comment: what a crappy system of azure. It should be unique to a tenant and each tenant should have as much isolation as it would be when on premise. Also helps hackers to hack. Ideally the url should contain: https://{vault-name}.{tenant-name}.vault.azure.net. What a design mishap !

Comment: Here's a link to an Azure feedback item, requesting to have key vault names being unique to a subscription: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/7477bcd4-321d-ed11-a81b-6045bd853c94

Comment: You could also add the tenant name to the vault name as a standard, while this is sorted